# How to add prefix from a fixed column to other columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, cbind

I would like to join a prefix from a fixed column like: "user" to other columns from in mergall database. Please, find the example below:

```
user    BenList1             BenList2
user14  beneficiary_649      beneficiary_1312
user16  beneficiary_1151     beneficiary_1660
user22  beneficiary_1320     beneficiary_468
```

The output is expecting like this:

```
user    BenList1                        BenList2
user14  user14,beneficiary_649          user14,beneficiary_1312
user16  user16,beneficiary_1151         user16,beneficiary_1660
user22  user22,beneficiary_1320         user22,beneficiary_468
```

For easy understanding I am showing here only two columns BenList1 and BenList2, in the original data sets there have BenList1: BenList60

```
mrgnw1<-mergeall$BenList1 <- paste(mergeall$User, mergeall$Ben1,sep=",")
mrgnw2<-mergeall$BenList2 <- paste(mergeall$User, mergeall$Ben2,sep=",")
```

To do this I tried the above code, It is working, but I am searching a way to create a loop to avoid writing codes for 60 times for 60 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
df[-1] <- sapply(df[-1], function(i)paste(df$user, i, sep = ','))

df
#    user                BenList1                BenList2
#1 user14  user14,beneficiary_649 user14,beneficiary_1312
#2 user16 user16,beneficiary_1151 user16,beneficiary_1660
#3 user22 user22,beneficiary_1320  user22,beneficiary_468
```

Comment: Dear Sotos, Thanks for your prompt suggestion. Should we write anything in function (i)? I copied your suggestion, pasted and run by changing "df", but not working. Can you please, elaborate it bit more? Thanks for your support.

Comment: What is the error? Are your columns factors or characters? (they should be characters)

Comment: The code you suggested is running well without generating any error. After running the code, no change is happening in the input and output file. It is same without any change. That means not adding like: user14,beneficiary_649 then user14,beneficiary1312.....

Comment: If you notice we assign at the beginning, i.e. `df[-1] <- ...`. This means that df will update all its columns except the first

Comment: Hi Sotos, Yes, I got your point that it needs to be updated all the columns except the first. But in reality, I found the output, it is just adding a "," (the separator), but missing to join the prefix from user column. It is showing like: BenList1: ,beneficiary_649; BenList2: ,beneficiary_1312. But not giving the desired output: BenList1: user14,beneficiary_649; BenList2: user14,beneficiary_1312. Probably need to think something in a different way.

Comment: I see you have the same problem with the other answer too. This means that you shared a wrong data frame. Make sure to share a **reproducible** example of your data frame (use `dput()`)

Answer (score 0):

In tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("BenList")), function(y) paste(.$user,y,sep=","))
    user                BenList1                BenList2
1 user14  user14,beneficiary_649 user14,beneficiary_1312
2 user16 user16,beneficiary_1151 user16,beneficiary_1660
3 user22 user22,beneficiary_1320  user22,beneficiary_468
```

This will work if there are other variables that you want to exclude distributed within your data.frame.

Comment: Dear James, Thanks for your response. Should we write anything in function (y). I copied it and changed "x" with my data name but not working. Sorry for bothering. I am very new in R, but very strong in VBA

Comment: The `y` is the anonymous variable that will get filled in by the `mutate_at` function. I originally has the first variable in paste as `x$user` but replaced it with `.$user` which should draw it from the original data in the chain (`x`) in this case, but something different in yours. What is the error that comes up?

Comment: It is producing the list as usual. That means not concatenating like: user14,beneficiary_649

Comment: Then I suspect it is because you're not selecting the variables to mutate correctly. Do they all start with BenList?

Comment: you can use `user` directly instead of `.$user`. `df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("BenList")), ~paste(user,.,sep=","))`

Comment: @Nazrul This will return the mutated data, but the original data frame won't change unless you assign to it. Is that what isn't working?

Comment: @ RonakShah, Thanks for your suggestion, I tested it and showing the error: "Error in paste(user, ., sep = ",") : object 'user' not found"

Comment: Hi James, is the code you suggested working in your end? My end it is just adding a "," before, Like: BenList1: ,beneficiary_649; BenList2: ,beneficiary_1312. That means it is taking the separator value to join two fields together, but missing to take the value from "user" field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, who provided support to solve the issues. I make the solution of the problem and here it is:

```
# The sample data was:   
mergeall <- data.frame(User = c("User14","User16","User22"),
                       BenList1 = c("beneficiary_6419","beneficiary_1151","beneficiary_1320"),
                       BenList2 = c("beneficiary_1312","beneficiary_16660","beneficiary_468"))

    #Create separate data frame for BenList1 and BenList2
    library(dplyr)
    for(i in 2:3)
      {temp<-select(mergeall,1,i)
      colnames(temp)[2] <- 'BenX' 
      Ben <- paste(temp$User,temp$BenX, sep=',')
      (temp <- cbind(temp, Ben))
      temp<-select(temp,"Ben")
      colnames(temp) <- paste0("Ben_List",i-1)
      assign(colnames(mergeall)[i], temp)
      rm(temp,Ben)
      }

    # Merge all data frame together
    mergeall<-cbind(mergeall,BenList1,BenList2)

    #Select column "User" and all new columns
    mergeall<-select(mergeall,1,4:5)

    #Remove all elements like: variable, data frame except the final data frame

    ls() 
    rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "mergeall"))

# The output is:

    User               Ben_List1                Ben_List2
    1 User14 User14,beneficiary_6419  User14,beneficiary_1312
    2 User16 User16,beneficiary_1151 User16,beneficiary_16660
    3 User22 User22,beneficiary_1320   User22,beneficiary_468
```

Hope to comeback with new problems in future to solve it together.